# Why do Pandas dataframe's data types change after exporting into a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory, export-to-excel

I did export the following dataframe in Google Colab. Whichever method I used, when I import it later, my dataframe appears as `pandas.core.series.Series`, not as an `array`.

[image]

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/output.csv'

with open(path, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
  df_protein_final.to_csv(f)
```

**After importing the dataframe** looks like below

[image]

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

***Note: The first image and second image can be different order in terms of numbers (It can be look as a different dataset). Please don't get hung up on this. Don't worry. Those images are just an example.***

Why does column, which is originally an `array` before exporting, converts to `series` after exporting?

The code below gives the same result. Can't export original structure.

```
from google.colab import files
df.to_csv('filename.csv') 
files.download('filename.csv')
```

**Edit:** I am looking for a solution is there any way to keep original structure (e.g. `array`) while exporting.

Comment: I suggest you to edit your questions title to more generalized one. Your current title is sepecific about `Colab`. But this problem occures not only in colab. So I suggest a title like `Why do Pandas dataframe's  data types change after exporting into a CSV file`

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is confusing. Please clarify what you mean by "which is originally an `array` before exporting, converts to `series`".  Every single column of a DataFrame is a `pandas.Series` regardless of its values' datatype (e.g. floats, numpy arrays, strings). Based on the discussion in the comments below, it seems that you mean that, before you export,  the values of column `ColumnA` of `df_protein_final` are `numpy` arrays, but when you read the file, the values of the same column are strings. Is my interpretation of the problem correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that is how pandas work. When you try to insert a list or an numpy array into a pandas dataframe, it converts that array to a series always. If you want to turn the series back to a list/array use `Series.values`, `Series.array` or `Series.to_numpy()` . refer [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html)

**EDIT :**

I got an idea from your comments. You are asking to save dframe into a file while preserving its all properties. You are actually (intentionally or unintentionally) asking how to SERIALIZE the data frame. You have to use `pickle` for this. Refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Note : Pandas has inbuilt pickle support. So you can directly export dframe into pickle file like in this example

```
df.to_pickle(file_name)
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution is there any way to keep original structure after exporting.

Comment: @drorhun Ah, you may asking how to keep order in the list in the cell values right?

Comment: @drorhun Why are you storing a whole array within a cell

Comment: What is your suggestion ? I am using as an input for deep learning model for each timestep.

Comment: @drorhun To give a suggestion i have to understand your problem accordingly. In the title you have asked about data type. But in context you are asking about the array order is being changed

Comment: @drorhun I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: I've never mentioned about array order changing. I am talkin about I have a array type data column like first image. After exporting, and importing I am getting Series data column.

Comment: @drorhun I think you re asking about the missing comma `,`

Comment: This is not just a missing `,` problem. First dataset is array and all of them are float and you can do math on it. After importing dataset was turned into text (Pandas Series). I am not able to do math operations.

Comment: @drorhun give me few minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245672/discussion-between-kavindu-ravishka-and-drorhun).